# Saving file from Firebase storage as .pdf?

Tags: javascript, firebase, pdf, firebase-storage

- In a web application, I want the user to be able to download a PDF file from Firebase Storage.
- Showing the PDF file in the browser works fine, but when the user tries to save the file on his local drive, it does not save automatically as .pdf. The user has to manually add ".pdf" at the end of the file name in the "Save as" window.
- How can I make it save as .pdf by default?

Here is my code

```js
document.getElementById('downloadFile' + doc.id).addEventListener('click', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    const ref = firebase.storage().ref().child('files').child(doc.id).child('file');

    // Get the download URL
    ref.getDownloadURL()
        .then(function (url) {
            window.open(url, '_blank');
        }).catch(function (error) {

            // A full list of error codes is available at
            // https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/handle-errors
            switch (error.code) {
                case 'storage/object-not-found':
                    alert('There is no file attached to this profile.')
                    break;

                case 'storage/unauthorized':
                    // User doesn't have permission to access the object
                    break;

                case 'storage/canceled':
                    // User canceled the upload
                    break;


                case 'storage/unknown':
                    // Unknown error occurred, inspect the server response
                    break;
            }
        });

});
```

Comment: Has your file the correct extension? And is the `type` set to `application/pdf`?

Comment: Thanks, the file that I upload has the correct extension. But where can I et the type to application/pdf? This is how I define the file where I upload it:        
const ref = firebase.storage().ref().child('files').child(DocId);
        const file = document.querySelector('#selectedFILE' + DocId).files[0];
        const name = file.name;

        const metadata = {
            contentType: file.type
        };

Comment: `const metadata = { contentType: file.type };` is correct. Is `file.type` having the correct value?

Comment: Yes the file.type returns "application/pdf". I just found out that the error comes from the fact that I force name the file 'file', thus removing the .pdf extension. Now I just need to figure out how to pass the file.name variable from my updload function to my download function. I can't see how to access file.name from outside the upload function. Thanks for the hint!